# How to correctly handle software licenses?(code under GPL3 making use of code under Apache2)

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, license-notice

I'm new to work in software developing by myself and I'm not sure what is the correct way to handle licenses, so far I'm working on a java project using maven (google json simple and junit pugins).

Maven and its plugins are under Apache2 license, as I'm nor editing java or anything like that from what I have read theres no need to include any license from it and my own code would go under GPL3.

As far as I have seen the license of the project go usually inside a "Lincense.txt", that's where I put the GPL3 but I'm unsure of the correct way to handle the Apache2 licenses.

Edit: making the question more clear.

**I have maven and some plugins for it under apache2 license, where should I put the apache2 license and what clarifications should I add?**

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify what you are asking exactly?

Comment: Done, tell me if you need any more details and thanks for your time, I'm struggling to understand the legalese.

Comment: Can you clarify more: your own code is going to be GPL-3 licensed? and you use dependencies as-is from Maven central that are Apache-licensed? is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, all correct.